# Matlab: How to color a region

Tags: matlab, colors

I am wishing to use Matlab to achieve the following goal:
I have a function that takes in two inputs and gives a real number.

```
function T = SS(x,y)
%%% some calculation %%%
T = returnval
```

I want the point (x,y) in the x-y plane to be coloured blue if the return value is equal to 1, green if the return value is equal to 0.5 etc.

I don't know how to approach this.
(the calculation is complicated so it is not obvious what's the relationship between x and y with respect to z. Thus can't write an equation to divide the region then colour accordingly.)

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can group all your `T`'s into a vector, you can use `scatter` to make the plot. Then just setup your own colormap. Here's an example:

```
%// Sample data
[x,y]=meshgrid(0:.1:2);
x=x(:);y=y(:);
T=rand(size(x));

%// Define the colormap
MAP=[1 0 0; %// red
    0 1 0;  %// green
    0 0 1]; %// blue
colormap(MAP) %// apply the colormap
scatter(x,y,[],T) %// make the plot
```

`MAP` is a matrix, and each row defines a colour. In this case, there are three rows, so elements with values between 0 and 1/3 will be red, elements with values between 1/3 and 2/3 will be green, and elements between 2/3 and 1 will be blue. In general, the range of `T` values (i.e. `max(T)-min(T)`) is evenly divided into each colour defined by `MAP`.

Comment: Thank you. Right now I am able to get a 100*100 matrix with elements of value of either 1/2/3/4/5/6. and I want all the 1's to be the same color, all the 2's to be the same color. Is your approach still applicable or is there an easier way to solve the problem? (since it's less complicated now.) Thanks.

Comment: In that case, make `MAP` with one row for each value. So if your values are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, then make `MAP` with 6 rows and 3 columns. Each row has 3 entries, one each for amount of red, green and blue, respectively. So `[1 1 1]` is white, `[0 0 0]` is black, `[1 0 0]` is red, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Going back to your first solution. What if the values of T's can't be determined before hand. Basically, what the function is doing is that it takes (x,y) and calculate 6 values (in a specific order) and returns the minimum. What I wanted to is that if the minimum returned is the second value calculated, then (x,y) should be red. If the minimum returned is the forth value calculated, then (x,y) should be another color. (Sorry if the description is complicated, thank you for your help)

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me. If you output the number that you want to use to set the colour as well as the value `T`, can you make another matrix with the colour information, then use that in `scatter`?